# Plot Multiple Roots in R

Tags: r, plot

I have an equation which I would like to solve for values of `m`

```
m^2+x*m+1=0
```

I know I can find these roots using `polyroot(c(1,x,1))`.

I'd like to plot these roots in R for varying `x` such that all the real roots of the polynomial are plotted for each value of `x`.

Note, the polynomial may become more complex than this, ruling out application of the quadratic or cubic formulas.

Any thoughts as to how I could accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this will do the trick. Just set `X` to whatever values you want to evaluate.

```
X <- seq(0, 10, length=21)
roots <- sapply(X, function(x) polyroot(c(1,x,1))) 
roots[abs(Im(roots)) > 1e-10] <- NA
matplot(X, t(roots), pch=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Be careful with checking that the imaginary part is zero - there may be some numerical artefacts that cause you to reject roots (eq x=2 in your graph). Better to check the absolute value is smaller than some tolerance amount)

Comment: Yup, noticed that too. Was a bit careless, but it's fixed now.

Comment: Hmmm... things work fine in your example. However, with my actual polynomial (`c(-0.2,0.1*(x/(x+0.1)),0,-0.0324,0.0027*(x/(x+0.1)))`) the `<-NA` line is returning "non-numeric argument to function" and the final line returns "'x' and 'y' must have the same number of rows". Any thoughts?

Comment: When `x=0` the last coefficient (`0.0027*(x/(x+0.1))`) is also zero giving you only three roots instead of 4. That prevents sapply to collapse the results into a matrix, but instead returns a list, which `Im()` does not allow. Change the polyroot command to `c(polyroot(...), NA)[1:4]` and it should work. A bit of a dirty workaround but it get's the job done.